# How do I store 2 variables in one list?

Tags: python, list, variables, python-3.x

I have a program that randomly encodes text using a key that continuously changes. the user also has the option to decode the text.

Essentially what I want to do is have a list containing the key that was used and what the encoded text was. For example, if I use the word `'test'` lets say it returns `BGMB` with the key for this word being `EIDTGRVHFNPSYJLKCWMBUXOZQA`. So in the list I would have `keyList = [(EIDTGRVHFNPSYJLKCWMBUXOZQA, BGMB)]` and the list would continue to grow as long as the user encodes words. I am sure I am doing this part correctly, `keyList.append((key, encodeText))`.

The problem I am having is I don't know what to do from here. I can continue encoding and it does continue to add it to the list. I am just not sure how to then access the list in the decode function. What I planned to do was to compare the user's inputted string that they want to decode and see if it was in the list, if it is, then the program would use the key for the word and send back the decoded string.

Any help you be wonderful. Thanks in advance!

Quick edit: here is the encode and decode method if that helps anyone

```
def encode(text):
    global key
    key = ''.join(random.sample(key, len(key)))
    switch = alpha.maketrans(alpha + alpha.lower(), key*2)
    encodeText = text.translate(switch)
    keyList.append((key, encodeText))
    print(keyList)
    return(encodeText)

def decode(text):
    print(keyList)
    switch = alpha.maketrans(key + key.lower(), alpha + alpha.lower())
    decodeText = text.translate(switch)
    return(decodeText)
```

The prints were their so I could see what is happening at each point.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use a `dict` for that. Since you want to access the encryption key by the encoded text, `encodeText` should be your dict key.

`keydict[ecodeText] = key`